# PHP How to exclude weekends and add attribute to holidays in months array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the all days for a given month as an array. Now I want to:

1) **Exclude the weekends**

2) **Holidays or Vacation periods**, these days should have an attribute like for example "isHoliday" - so that the array for example could look like this

```
[{
  "day" : "2018-09-03-Monday",
  "isHoliday" : false //or true if its a holiday 
}]
```

Is that possible?

My code so far:

```
$list=array();
$month = 9;
$year = 2018;

for($d=1; $d<=31; $d++)
{
   $time=mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $d, $year);          
    if (date('m', $time)==$month)       
       $list[]=date('Y-m-d-D', $time);
}

print_r($list);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the weekend check, you can do something similar to what you've done for the month check:

```
if(date('d', $time) !== 'Sat' && date('d', $time) !== 'Sun')
```

For the holiday check, search your array for the record for this day, and check the flag:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d-l', $time);
$isHoliday = false;
foreach($holidays as $entry)
{
    if($entry['day'] === $date)
    {
        $isHoliday = $entry['isHoliday'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: the weekend check is perfect. The holiday check is the one I can't get to work - what If the holidays is an array of dates and where should I place the check - inside my for loop?

Comment: Yes, inside the for loop, and then you can use $isHoliday in your conditional. Sorry, I had an error in my code there... the date() call should reference the $time you've created inside the loop.

Comment: If the holiday list is just an array of dates, then format the current time accordingly, and search the array similarly to the above - set $isHoliday = true if you find it.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you use already implemented solution for this: [yasumi](https://github.com/azuyalabs/yasumi)

It's simpe and very usefull library.

Example:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Use the factory to create a new holiday provider instance
$holidays = Yasumi\Yasumi::create('USA', 2018);

// Get the number of defined holidays
echo $holidays->count() . PHP_EOL;

// Get a list all of the holiday dates
foreach ($holidays->getHolidayDates() as $date) {
    echo $date . PHP_EOL;
}

// Check if date is holiday
$holidays->isHoliday(new Date())
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would prefer not to use a library

Comment: @ST80 sure, it's your choice.  But you can look in to this library source and get an example how they define holidays.